Next.js, NextAuth, Supabase: OAuth Login Returning Invalid ID Instead of UUID for Database Integration
I am developing a web platform with Next.js (version 14.2.11), NextAuth for authentication, and Supabase as the database. While email/password registration and login work seamlessly, I face issues with OAuth providers (Google and GitHub).
The OAuth login process completes successfully, but instead of receiving a valid UUID from the user session (as required by my database schema), I receive an invalid input syntax like 155546379251609383107. This prevents the proper integration of OAuth users into my database, as the id field in my auth.users table is a UUID type.
Database Setup:
auth > users (Supabase default)
id (UUID)
email (varchar)
Other fields (password, etc.)
public > profiles (custom)
id (UUID, foreign key to auth.users.id)
first_name (text)
last_name (text)
phone (text)
avatar_url (text)
provider_id (text)
Users should be able to log in via OAuth (Google or GitHub), and their profiles should be linked correctly in the profiles table.
Relevant Code Snippets
app\api\auth[...nextauth].js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import GitHubProvider from 'next-auth/providers/github';
import { SupabaseAdapter } from '@next-auth/supabase-adapter';
import { supabase } from '../../../lib/supabaseClient';

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "email", placeholder: "email@example.com" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const { email, password } = credentials;
        const { data, error } = await supabase
          .from('users')
          .select('*')
          .eq('email', email)
          .single();
        if (error || !data) {
          throw new Error('Invalid email or password');
        }
        if (data.password !== password) {
          throw new Error('Invalid email or password');
        }
        return { id: data.id, email: data.email, name: data.name };
      }
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    GitHubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  adapter: SupabaseAdapter(supabase),
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, user }) {
      session.user.id = user.id;
      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
      }
      return token;
    }
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
  },
});

app\lib\authOptions.js
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import GithubProvider from 'next-auth/providers/github';
import { supabase } from '../lib/supabaseClient';

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "email" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const { email, password } = credentials;
        const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
          email,
          password,
        });
    
        if (error || !data.user) {
          throw new Error('InvalidCredentials');
        }
    
        return { id: data.user.id, email: data.user.email };
      },
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,

  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user?.id) {
        token.user_id = user.id;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (token?.user_id) {
        session.user.id = token.user_id;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
};

app\login\page.js
'use client';

import { useState } from 'react';
import { signIn } from 'next-auth/react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

export default function LoginPage() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();

  const getErrorMessage = (error) => {
    switch (error) {
      case 'Callback':
        return 'Die Anmeldung wurde abgebrochen.';
      case 'CredentialsSignin':
        return 'Anmeldeinformationen sind ungültig.';
      case 'InvalidCredentials':
        return 'Ungültige E-Mail oder Passwort.';
      default:
        return 'Ein unbekannter Fehler ist aufgetreten.';
    }
  };

  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    setError('');

    const result = await signIn('credentials', {
      redirect: false,
      email,
      password,
    });

    if (result?.error) {
      setError(result.error);
    } else {
      router.push('/dashboard');
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center min-h-screen p-6">
      <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-4">Anmelden</h1>

      {error && (
        <div className="bg-red-500 text-white p-4 rounded mb-4">
          {getErrorMessage(error)}
        </div>
      )}

      {/* E-Mail Login */}
      <form className="flex flex-col w-80 mb-8" onSubmit={handleLogin}>
        <input
          type="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="E-Mail-Adresse"
          className="mb-4 px-4 py-2 border rounded"
          required
        />
        <input
          type="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Passwort"
          className="mb-4 px-4 py-2 border rounded"
          required
        />
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="bg-[#003f56] text-white px-4 py-2 rounded hover:bg-[#004f66] transition"
          disabled={loading}
        >
          {loading ? 'Anmelden...' : 'Anmelden mit E-Mail'}
        </button>
      </form>

      {/* Login mit Google */}
      <button 
        className="flex items-center bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded hover:bg-blue-600 transition mb-4"
        onClick={() => signIn('google', { callbackUrl: '/dashboard' })}
      >
        <div className="bg-white p-1 rounded-full mr-2">
          <Image 
            src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c1/Google_%22G%22_logo.svg"
            alt="Google Logo"
            width={20}
            height={20}
          />
        </div>
        Anmelden mit Google
      </button>
      {/* Login mit GitHub */}
      <button 
        className="flex items-center bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded hover:bg-blue-600 transition mb-4"
        onClick={() => signIn('github', { callbackUrl: '/dashboard' })}
      >
        <div className="bg-white p-1 rounded-full mr-2">
          <Image 
            src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/25/25231.png"
            alt="Github Logo"
            width={20}
            height={20}
          />
        </div>
        Anmelden mit Github
      </button>


      <p className="mt-4">
        Du hast noch keinen Account? Registriere dich{' '}
        <Link href="/register" className="text-blue-500 hover:underline">
          hier
        </Link>
        {' '}ein.
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

What Works

Email/password authentication, registration, and profile updates work as expected.
OAuth login successfully authenticates the user but provides an ID in an incorrect format.

What Doesn't Work

The id provided by OAuth in the session is not compatible with the UUID format required by my database schema, resulting in errors when trying to write or fetch user data.

Goal
I want OAuth login to behave identically to email/password login. After a user logs in via Google or GitHub, their data should integrate seamlessly with the auth.users and public.profiles tables.
What I've Tried

Verified the Google/GitHub Client ID and Secret in the .env.local file.
Reviewed and tested the NextAuth provider configuration.
Checked if NextAuth correctly parses the OAuth user information and populates the session.
Ensured that the profiles table has no Row-Level Security (RLS) enabled.

What I Expect
After successful OAuth login, the user's UUID (auth.users.id) should be:

Correctly linked to their session in NextAuth.
Usable for database operations, particularly in the profiles table and further on other pages.

